# Powershell - set default font colour of text in a script

Tags: powershell, colors

I wonder if I can set default colour of text written with write-host, so I don't have to specify it every time with -foregroundcolor? If I have a script and want all text to be certain color unless explicitly set otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following makes all cmdlets that have a `-ForegroundColor` parameter - such as `Write-Host` - default to the value `Green`:

```
# Optionally create a scope-local empty copy of $PSDefaultParameterValues
# first.
# If you want to preserve any existing global entries in the local
# copy, use:
#   $PSDefaultParameterValues = $PSDefaultParameterValues.Clone()
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{}

$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:ForegroundColor'] = 'Green'
```

See the [documentation of the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values).

Note: If you create a scope-local copy as shown above, the original `$PSDefaultParameterValues` hashtable will take effect again when your script or function exits; that is, your `-ForegroundColor` default will go out of scope.
If you need to remove the default while still in your scope, use
`$PSDefaultParameterValues.Remove('*:ForegroundColor')`

---

In *console*-based hosts (console windows, Windows Terminal, Unix terminals - but *not* the ISE), if you want *all* output (including *implicit* output) to default to a given color (green in this example):

```
$host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Green'
```